# ArchUnit: Check only field method-calls

Tags: java, archunit

I need to make sure that classes annotated by `@Path` only call methods in classes annotated by `@Secured`. But only method-calls on fields (e.g. injected beans) should be checked. What I have so far is:

```
ArchRuleDefinition.classes().that()
        .areAnnotatedWith(Path.class)
        .or().areMetaAnnotatedWith(Path.class)
        .should().onlyCallMethodsThat(are(declaredIn(!!!))
```

So 2 parts are missing:

- The check that only calls on fields should be considered and not the ones on local variables
- The part in `declaredIn` to check that the methods should be declared in a class that has `@Secured`-annotation

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple **solution for the second part**: With

```java
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass;
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.HasOwner.Functions.Get;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.properties.CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.annotatedWith;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.classes;
```

you can use

```java
    classes()
            .that().areMetaAnnotatedWith(Path.class)
            .should().onlyCallMethodsThat(
                    Get.<JavaClass>owner().is(annotatedWith(Secured.class))
                            .as("are defined in classes annotated with @Secured")
            );
```

Note that `areMetaAnnotatedWith` also includes direct annoations since [ArchUnit 0.17.0](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.17.0). If you wanted to test constructor calls as well, you could replace `onlyCallMethodsThat` with `onlyCallCodeUnitsThat`.

---

Unfortunately, I don't think that the **first part** can be solved with the current version [ArchUnit 0.23.1](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.23.1): You can rewrite the above rule to test each [`JavaMethodCall`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMethodCall.html), which is more specific than the called [`JavaMethod`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaMethod.html):

```java
    noClasses()
            .that().areMetaAnnotatedWith(Path.class)
            .should().callMethodWhere(describe("owner is not @Secured",
                methodCall ->
                    !methodCall.getTargetOwner().isAnnotatedWith(Secured.class)
            ));
```

With [`JavaMethodCall#getOrigin()`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaAccess.html#getOrigin()), you can find the [`JavaCodeUnit`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.tngtech.archunit/archunit/latest/com/tngtech/archunit/core/domain/JavaCodeUnit.html) where the method call occured, but this does not include information about the object on which the method was called.

If I understood correctly, you want to distinguish the following cases:

```java
@Secured
class SecuredOwner {
    void method() {
    }
}

class NotSecuredOwner {
    void method() {
    }
}

@Path
class ThisShouldBeOkay {
    SecuredOwner securedOwner = new SecuredOwner();

    void call_secured_method_on_field() {
        securedOwner.method();
    }

    void call_not_secured_method_on_local_variable() {
        new NotSecuredOwner().method();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Do you have also an idea for the first part?

Comment: I fear that this is unfortunately not possible with the current version [ArchUnit 0.23.1](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit/releases/tag/v0.23.1). I'll extend my answer to describe why.

Comment: Your last code snippet is exactly what I wanted to do. OK, so I need to find another way to do a similar check. Thank you anyway, I'll accept the answer.